# If keys of two dictionaries are equal, perform operation using both values and move to new dict (python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, compare

I have two dictionaries, like this:

```
d1 = {'red':10, 'blue':20, 'green':30, 'yellow':40}
d2 = {'red':1, 'blue':2, 'green':3}
```

I want go through each item in d1 and see if the key matches a key in d2. If so, I want to subtract the d2 key from the d1 key, and move the new key/value pair into a new dictionary, resulting in:

```
d3 = {'red':9, 'blue':18, 'green':27, 'yellow':40}
```

I wrote the following script to do this:

```
for x, y in d1.items():
    for a, b in d2.items():
        if x == a:
            d3[x] = (y-b)
        elif x not in d2.items():
            d3[x] = y
```

This works, but when I try to use this on two dictionaries with thousands of items, the function never finishes. I guess it's way too slow.

Can you recommend a better way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need to iterate through `d2`. You can **look up** `x` in `d2`. That's what dictionaries are for.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? I would like to understand this.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you make things too complicated, simply use *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{k:v1-d2.get(k,0) for k,v1 in d1.items()}
```

This will generate:

```
>>> {k:v1-d2.get(k,0) for k,v1 in d1.items()}
{'red': 9, 'blue': 18, 'green': 27, 'yellow': 40}
```

The code works as follows: the dictionary comprehension will iterate through the `items()` of `d1`, with `k` the key and `v1` the value of `d1` that is associated with `k`.

Then for each such key-value pair, we will associate `v1-d2.get(k,0)` with the key `k` in the resulting dictionary. `d2.get(k,0)` will aim to fetch the value associated with `k`, and if the key is *not* in the dictionary, it will return `0`.

The algorithm runs - given dictionary lookup can happen in *O(1)* (not guaranteed, but very likely) - in *O(n)* with *n* the number of elements in `d1`, so reasonably fast.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense... When you say "that is associated with `k1`" do you mean "that is associated with `k`", since there is no `k1` in the code?

Comment: @ddrsee: yeah, appologies for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your help. And if you have a favorite webpage with which to learn dict comprehensions don't hesitate to share it! :-)

Comment: @ddrsee: updated with a reference to the documentation about dictionary comprehension here on SO.

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dict comprehension with an if-else statement:

```
d1 = {'red':10, 'blue':20, 'green':30, 'yellow':40}
d2 = {'red':1, 'blue':2, 'green':3}

new_dict = {a:b-d2[a] if a in d2 else b for a, b in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'blue': 18, 'green': 27, 'red': 9, 'yellow': 40}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record (as I find *dictionary comprehension* pretty elegant) you can also use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (which is also pretty neat) for this task :

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: d1 = {'red':10, 'blue':20, 'green':30, 'yellow':40}
   ...: d2 = {'red':1, 'blue':2, 'green':3}
   ...: 

In [3]: A = Counter(d1)

In [4]: B = Counter(d2)

In [5]: A - B
Out[5]: Counter({'blue': 18, 'green': 27, 'red': 9, 'yellow': 40})
```

As pointed in comments by @WillemVanOnsem,

> "if a value in d2 is higher than its corresponding one in d1, we will
>   not obtain a negative number, but the key will disappear: a counter
>   usually assumes counts which are natural numbers".

However there is another solution relying on `Counter` by using its `substract()` method *(only introduced in python 3.2)*, but it will modify one of your `Counter` object (as it behaves as `dict.update()` :

```
In [26]: A = Counter({'red':10, 'blue':20, 'green':30, 'yellow':40})
    ...: B = Counter({'red':1, 'blue':30, 'green':3})
    ...: 

In [27]: A - B # The 'blue' key disappear 
Out[27]: Counter({'green': 27, 'red': 9, 'yellow': 40})

In [28]: A.subtract(B) # It handles negative values ...

In [29]: A # ...but modify the counter A
Out[29]: Counter({'blue': -10, 'green': 27, 'red': 9, 'yellow': 40})
```

The main purpose of `collections.Counter` is notably to count/store the occurrences of hashable objects (thus assuming counts which are natural numbers) but it is basically a subclass of [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) which provide several operations for combining `Counter` objects between them (addition, subtraction, union and intersection).

Comment: If a value in `d2` is higher than its corresponding one in `d1`, we will *not* obtain a negative number, but the key will disappear: a counter usually assumes counts which are natural numbers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem good catch, thanks! I will update with the appropriate method for this case.